# merging multiple data frames of unequal length and with multiple ocurences of the same column values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have three data frames I want to merge, but so far it's just turned into a giant mess.

The first dataset, rank_table contains each competitors stats (rank, total points, championships etc.)

The second dataset, winners, contains the names of all competitors who placed in a competition

The third dataset, master.treeDQ2, contains all match information between competitors (who competed against who, division, weight, etc)

I want to merge all three dataframes but they are all unequal lengths. A complication is that in the third dataset, there are two competitor names in each row (comp01_name and comp02_name), so I cannot create unique ID's. Also, there are competitors that appear in both comp01_name comp02_name columns, while some only appear in one or the other.

I made an attempt to merge the three data frames, but as I got closer to the end, I realized it was turning into a giant mess!

Ideally, the final data frame should only provide the ranking information (rank_table) and placement information (winners) for **one occurrence** of each competitors name in master.treeDQ2.

Is this even possible? HELP!

```
library(dplyr)

rank_table = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/rank_table_complete2.csv')

winners = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/winners.csv')

master.treeDQ2 = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/master.treeDQ.edited_draft6.csv')

# rename winner column as Competitor
names(winners)[6] <- 'Competitor'

# merge rank table and winner table
df = merge(rank_table, winners, by = "Competitor",
                  all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)

# merge df with master.treeDQ3

master.treeDQ3 = master.treeDQ2

# change comp01_name to Competitor
names(master.treeDQ3)[11] <- 'Competitor'

# merge df with master.treeDQ3 for comp01_name
master.treeDQ3 = merge(master.treeDQ3, df, by = "Competitor", all.x = TRUE, all.y = T)

# change comp01_name to Competitor
master.treeDQ3 <- master.treeDQ3 %>%
  rename(comp01_name = Competitor) %>% 
  relocate(comp01_name, .before = comp01_club)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the unique competitors out of `master.treeDQ2`, then join in the info from the other two tables. E.g. something like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

# first fix competitor name in rank_table
my_rank_table <- mutate(rank_table, Competitor = str_remove(Competitor, '\n'))

tibble(Competitor = unique(c(master.treeDQ2$comp01_name, master.treeDQ2$comp02_name))) %>% 
  left_join(my_rank_table, 'Competitor') %>% 
  left_join(winners, 'Competitor')
```

Comment: Nice! if I want to merge this new tibble with the `master.treeDQ2` data frame, what would I merge them by so that all the information is matched up with the correct competitor in `master.treeDQ2` ?

Comment: Nice! How would you merge the tibble with `master.treeDQ2`? I tried using the same method you used to merge the `rank_table` and `winners`, but it merged giving incorrect values for some columns. I also tried a few other methods which also produced the same result